# Magento 2.4.0-1 Bitnami Stack for Mac is very slow

Tags: magento2.4

I installed Magento 2.4.0-1 Bitnami Stack on my Mac and the pages are loading extremely slowly. Even when I already see the picture of the home page, it keeps loading.

I’m using MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012), Processor 2,6 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7, Memory 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3.

Is there a solution to make pages load fast?

What is the best development environment btw (preferrably local)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use docker-sync if you use docker with Mac

see some info at: https://dev.to/kovah/cut-your-docker-for-mac-response-times-in-half-with-docker-sync-1e8j

Comment: thanks for reply but i’m not using a docker. i just downloaded the installer from bitnami and launched it. currently trying to set up local development environment but there are lots of issues... could you advice a good solution for local setup?

Comment: I use https://github.com/rafaelstz/Magento2Docker since last 3 months and it does work really well (I am on linux though). If you are on mac, best bet may be valet-plus; if you are devops a bit, install a native lemp stack has worked well for me too

Comment: thanks a lot! will try it.